# How to get the key of an index in a TreeMap

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, indexing, key, treemap

I want to get a key from it's index in a `TreeMap`. I can do this in Java `Object firstKey = myMap.keySet().toArray()[index];`
 But how can I achieve the same in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same in Kotlin using `map.keys.elementAt(index)`

```kotlin
import java.util.TreeMap

fun main() {
   val index = 0
   val map = TreeMap<String, String>()
   map.put("1", "Test")
   map.put("2", "Test2")
   val obj = map.keys.elementAt(index)
   print(obj)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use [index] but i had to use elementAt(index) :)

Comment: @Marek you could write  `map.put("1", "Test")` as `map["1"] = "Test"` which is more Kotlinish :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to stick to the `toArray()[index]` call for some reason, you can use `myMap.keys.toTypedArray()[index]`, see the example below:

```
import java.util.TreeMap

fun main() {
    val map = TreeMap<String, String>()
    map.put("key", "value")
    println(map.keys.toTypedArray()[0])
}
```

Otherwise, @Marek's approach using `myMap.keys.elementAt(index)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Marek's is (maybe) easier to read and yours will be faster. So they're both good :)